# How can I fix "Dirty Cow" bug on my Ubuntu 1604?

Tags: kernel, updates

I've just read somewhere about "Dirty Cow" bug, and I'm a new user of Ubuntu 1604.

- How can I know my kernel version?
- How to fix this bug?
- Am I in danger of hacking?

Thanks you all for your helps.

Comment: @fkraiem The linked question was about What and this is about how to fix.

Comment: @Anwar No, it was not, if you would read beyond the title.

Comment: @fkraiem Please, be nice. Not everyone reads every questions. That didn't notice that one before. From your link, I quickly glanced over it. No answers (despite being lengthy) explicitly shows how to fix that. One mentions to upgrade kernel, but You cannot assume that much smartness from a user who asked this question. Btw, I agreed after reading the question that it is a duplicate.

Comment: What should I do? Delete this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All is here : [Dirty Cow](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-protect-your-server-against-the-dirty-cow-linux-vulnerability)

- How can I know my kernel version

$ uname -rv

If your version is earlier than the following, you are affected:
4.4.0-45.66 for Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
4.8.0-26.28 for Ubuntu 16.10
3.13.0-100.147 for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
3.2.0-113.155 for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

- How to fix this bug

Just do an apt-get upgrade

- Am I in danger of hacking

Exploiting this bug means that a regular, unprivileged user on your server can gain write access to any file they can read, and can therefore increase their privileges on the system. [More infos](http://Exploiting%20this%20bug%20means%20that%20a%20regular,%20unprivileged%20user%20on%20your%20server%20can%20gain%20write%20access%20to%20any%20file%20they%20can%20read,%20and%20can%20therefore%20increase%20their%20privileges%20on%20the%20system)